# ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON - How to map an array of JSON from a returned string to an collection of Ruby objects

Tags: ruby, active-model-serializers, activemodel

I have code that works for a single instance but the API I am consuming returns an array of data. I have a class to encapsulate this data:

```
class Brewery
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON

  attr_accessor :id, :name

  def attributes=(hash)
    hash.each { |key, value| send("#{key}=", value) }
  end

  def attributes
    instance_values
  end
end
```

And what the returned data looks like is similar to this

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Avondale Brewing Co"
    },
    {
        "id": 44,
        "name": "Trim Tab Brewing"
    }
]
```

I can marshal a single JSON hash to the class with code such as this:

```
brewery = Brewery.new
brewery.from_json(single_brewery)
```

However this doesn't work with the array. I'm relatively new with Ruby so I'm not quite sure what the function to use is or to at least complete the JSON hashes to an array I can map `from_json` over.

This works but seems clunky

```
breweries = JSON.parse(brewery_list).map { |b|
  brewery = Brewery.new
  brewery.from_json(b.to_json)
}
```

Comment: I started on writing an answer showing how you can monkeypatch the `ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON` module for your needs, but honestly I would recommend just writing your own module for this, since the functionality won't be that complicated and it sounds like you already know what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure why do you find mapping an array clunky, but you might turn your `Brewery` to be a factory.

```rb
class Brewery
  ...

  def self.many(brewery_list)
    JSON.parse(brewery_list).
         map(&:to_json).
         map(&Brewery.new.method(:from_json)
  end
end
```

And use it like this

```rb
breweries = Brewery.many(brewery_list)
```

Comment: It's more that having to call JSON.parse to then calling to_json followed by from_json in the same call didn't feel right. If that's how it's done that's how it's done.